# BehaviorSubject observable triggers many times

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I subsribed to observable of behaviorSubject and it's triggers too many times. It happens only when i am navigating on the same component route, as an example...folder-folder-folder and now ...delete file triggers x3 times.

Subscribe code:

```
this.headerService.selectedItems.subscribe( {
 next:(value) =>
if (this.selectedRowsIds.size >= 1 && value === true) {
this.deleteDocs();
}... and here value comes x3 times
```

BehaviorSubject:

```
deleteButton = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
 selectedItems = this.deleteButton.asObservable();
```

```
deleteTrigger(trigger: boolean) : void {
this.deleteButton.next(trigger);
}
```

I tried to unsubcribe, to send false trigger everytime when i navigate, but nothing changes.

I mention that component DOES NOT DESTROY in this case, cause we open folder-folder-folder on the same component, with changing route params.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem can due to many other factors

1. Due to any change in route in the process.
2. Due to Not emitting value at right time.
3. Behavior Subject fires the value as soon as its initialized `new BehaviorSubject<any>({})` with an `{}` (and empty object it emits and this value it holds )

**Insufficient working and dependable code to see the  flow , if possible please provide insight.**

My Solution:

```
deleteButton :BehaviorSubject<boolean>= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

deleteTrigger(trigger: boolean) : void {
this.deleteButton.next(trigger);
}
```

**trigger: boolean   (here we are only emitting boolean values because input is always boolean)**

```
   this.headerService.deleteButton.subscribe(response => {
       if(response) {
     this.selectedRowsIds.size >= 1 && value === true ? 
           this.deleteDocs() : '';
       }
   });
```

this would subscribe to the action when a value is emitted from **deleteButton** and the value is **true** then it would excute desired logic though tenary opeartor

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs takeLast with behavior subject to fix the issue or Promise Resolve.  takeLast, you could also use take, takeOnce all found in rxjs.  Also you do not need to strong type your interfaces on behavior subjects.  It's recommended for security concerns. because any is applied.

Also you should make your subscription async and await the answer from the subscription.

[RXJS LINK](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take)

**rxjs**

```
import { BehaviorSubject, takeLast, tap } from 'rxjs';
  private yourSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
//or your choice
  private yourSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
//or your choice
  private yourSubject = new BehaviorSubject({} as any);
  public yourSubject$ = this.yourSubject.asObservable();
    this.yourSubject$.pipe(takeLast(1),tap((item)=>{return item})).subscribe()
```

**Promise resolve**

```
this.yourSubject$.subscribe((element)=>{
 const item = Promise.resolve(element)
 return item;
});
//or your choice
this.yourSubject$.subscribe(async (element)=> {
 const item = await element;
 return item;
})
```